# Form getting submitted even if submit button is disabled

Tags: forms, submit, form-submit, disabled-input

I have a form where I have disabled the submit button. This button only gets enabled if I select a value of the dropdown. But I got a strange issue in IE and Chrome: if I press enter in the textbox, the form gets submitted (even though my submit button is disabled).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Submit</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="/distributor-locations-global/index.html?qa=Y" >
            <input type="hidden" value="" id="filter-url" name="filter_url">
            <input type="hidden" value="SKF Distributor" id="filter_type" name="filter_type">
            <input type="hidden" value="Y" id="filter_type" name="identifier">  
            <div class="field country-field full">
                <select id="country" name="country" class="custom replaced" title="Sweden">
                    <option value="">Select location *</option>
                     <option value="1042">Albania</option>
                      <option value="1043">Algeria</option>
                      <option value="1064">Benin</option>
                </select>
            </div>      

            <div class="field zip-field full">
                <input type="text"  id="zip" name="zip" class="ui-disabled styled-text" >
            </div>

            <div class="button"><input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Show results" class="button styled-button"></div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Submit button is not only way to submit the form, if you want to set some restrictions of form submit you have to use js function like this

1. add onsubmit="return validate();" in your form tag 
   e.g. `<form method="post" action="/distributor-locations-global/index.html?qa=Y" onsubmit="return validate();">`
2. add appropriate javascript function

   ```
   <script>
   function validate() 
   {
       if (check_what_you_need_here==true) {
           return true;
       }

       return false;
   }
   </script>
   ```

now each time form will be about to submit it will go to validate method, and only after it passes validation form will be send

Comment: But Firefox handles it properly, its IE and Chrome which doesnt... Thanks for the reply btw, i had kept this as a alternative option, but just wanted to know if i am doing something wrong in the html..

Comment: Well, different browsers handle form submission in different ways, it is not something statically defined. regarding to your html it looks legit though I don't see the part where dropdown selection activates submit button.
the rule is that you better have to one general solution than several specific, in our case form onSubmit works on all browsers that's why I would prefer build my logic on it rather than on specific enable-disable.

Answer (score 0):

you could disable the enter key on the form by using the below code in your header:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

    function stopRKey(evt) { 
      var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
      var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
      if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
    } 

    document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 

    </script>
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot for the answer.. its a good way.. but not the best way of doing it.. i think i would use a JS fix for this one.. But thanks a lot for the super quick response :)